# Google sheets: Filter sheet so it shows or selects only columns containing string

Tags: google-sheets, multiple-columns, spreadsheet

I have a google sheet with many columns, and I want to select (or filter) all of the columns whose labels contain the string "xyz" in them. Is there any simple way to do this?

The only way I've been able to do this so far is by Cmd + F to search the sheet for "xyz" and then manually select all of the columns with my mouse.

Context: The data is from a survey where participants evaluated 10 products. For each product, they answered the same set of questions. The way the data reads out to a sheet, each question gets a column. So that means there are 10 columns, for example, where I'm asking "how likely would you buy this product?" I want to select all 10 columns that ask how likely they would buy x product so that I can copy these columns, paste them into a new tab, and analyze them. These 10 columns all contain in their labels the string "how_likely", so I'm trying to select these columns by somehow searching for all columns that contain that string.

Comment: I think, in order to offer suggestions, those here will need to know WHY you want to select only those columns. For instance, if you only want to be able to view them together, I'd suggest one approach. If you need to be able to make changes to them, I'd suggest another. If you're wanting to search for something within those columns and do something further with that information, I'd suggest yet another approach. The more you can tell us in your post, the greater the likelihood that suggestions made here will be useful to you.

Comment: Hi Eric, here's some context: The data is from a survey where participants evaluated 10 products. For each product, they answered the same set of questions. The way the data reads out to a sheet, each question gets a column. So that means there are 10 columns, for example, where I'm asking "how likely would you buy this product?" I want to select all 10 columns that ask how likely they would buy x product so that I can copy these columns, paste them into a new tab, and analyze them.

Comment: Sounds like what you want to do can be done entirely with formulas. However, the best way to convey how would be to SHOW you in a sample spreadsheet. I encourage you to  set up a sample spreadsheet. You don't need to connect it to a form, but do include, say, five realistic rows of data in Sheet1 (perhaps renamed "Form Data"). Then manually enter into a second sheet an example of what you might like to see there. Given that much information, either I or someone else here should be able to assist you. Just be sure to set the link's Share permission to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor."

Comment: Thanks, here's a sample dataset I put together: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14zodizG8zOAx0iN9H6udivfTm2LjR1HDMVcPB1Y6u8I/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The ultimate goal is to plot visually the performance of these brands and find patterns through these visualizations.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by doing a couple of preparation steps as follows:

1. Create a sheet where you list the unique part of the question title (eg. "how_appropriate" , etc.). I named it "QuestionsList" and it looks like this:
   [image]
2. Create a sheet where you transpose the data in "FormData". I called this sheet "TransposedFormData" and it looks like this:[image]

Use `=TRANSPOSE(FormData!A1:H16)` in cell A2 for it. *I wrote the header names for easier visualization, but they aren't required.*

---

Now that you have the data prepared, lets get the desired output.
In the sheet "DesiredOutput" in cell A1, write the following formula:

> `=Transpose(QUERY(TransposedFormData!A:P,"select * where A contains '"&QuestionsList!A1&"'",0))`

Notice the desired output: [image] corresponds to only one question (the one listed in `QuestionsList!A1`). So you will need a "DesiredOutput" sheet for each of the question titles, and on each change the row number in `QuestionsList!A*` where "*" represents the row number of the question title you want.

Comment: Thanks! Transposing the master data set solved it. Now I can easily filter, select, and copy the questions.

Comment: Im glad it helped. Please consider upvoting/accepting the answer if it worked for you. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers